# Three dimensional curved space-time

Tags: geometry, general-relativity

I have an idea on how to visualize curved space-time in three dimensions, but I'm having trouble finding images to confirm the way I see it. Can someone please provide good images or links to galleries of curved space-time in three dimensions? I want to see an illustration of a black hole in three dimensions.

Comment: This may help? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155328/visualizing-gravity-in-3d

Comment: Tom Giblin's 2003 [senior thesis](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-gr-qc0305102) may be worth a look. It's mathematically substantive, but contains a large number of embedding diagrams (and not just for the Schwarzschild metric). The caveat is, they're isometric embeddings into _Minkowski_ space, not Euclidean space.